# Google Play Market account for different applications

Tags: android, google-play

I'm starting developing and app about fights and violence and i'm planning to distribute this app through the Google Play Market, like i did with all my other Android apps. I usually develop and publish apps for children, so i'm scared about publish something that is really far from my other published apps. For example I'm scared about the fact that an user, while is looking for one of my child related app, can see the violence app in the "other apps from this developer" section.
Is there a way to avoid that or the only solution is to buy another developer account?

Comment: Yes, you will need another developer account, which, if you think about it, is good, because you will have an account for children apps and other for adult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, *More from Developer* and related search on site and Play app is based on developer's name.

For example, search for more from developer looks like this: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=publisher_name` and for devices `market://search?q=pub:publisher_name`

The only option is to register separate Google Play publisher account.

Answer (score 0):

To create another account for the sheer purpose of publishing an application which is violent and should not be seen by users of your other applications, is purely a subjective matter. If you believe this is the best way of doing so, go right ahead. I don't see how it will affect any other factor.

That being said, when you publish an application, you already have the option (a mandatory one, I might add) to select the **Content Rating**. The recommended selection for such an application could be *High Maturity*. Read more about it at this [link](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188189).